# Apache Camel Http Client initiating TLSv1 handshake with IBM Java runtime

Tags: java, apache-camel, websphere

Using Apache Camel version 3.14 with spring boot

Java runtime is IBM Java 8.0

Calling a client enpoint :

.to("endpoint?bridgeEndpoint=true&okStatusCodeRange=200-310,400-501")

getting the below exception:

DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:430 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1]
2022-09-01T12:37:25,379Z 27130 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:431 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
2022-09-01T12:37:25,379Z 27130 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 - Starting handshake
2022-09-01T12:37:25,414Z 27165 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:96 - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2022-09-01T12:37:25,415Z 27166 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:129 - Connection discarded

caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

I understand that the remote server is disconneting the server as the handshake is TLSv1.

How can I force the SSLConnectionSocketFactory to use TLSv1.2 via camel.

When I use a different java runtime (Example oracle JRE 8.xx), i am not getting this error. I tried setting the below VM args too:

/app/product/mw9/java/8.0/jre/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: java -fullversion may help

Comment: @covener Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3ifix-20160615_01(SR3+IX90173+IV85763))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160615_308126 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

Comment: It looks like com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS was introduced right around 2016, I suspect it's not in your build though.  2016 is incredibly old.

Comment: Thanks anyways, yes there was no workaround, updated the java run time and it resolved the issue.